# How to extract TimeZone from Date object?

Tags: swift, datetime, swift3, timezone

I have an ISO-8601 date string like this: `"2017-02-07T00:00:00-08:00"`.

How can I extract the TimeZone object from this date?

Comment: There is no timezone in a `Date` object. Please clarify what you actually want.

Comment: I have updated the question, thx.

Comment: You don't have a time zone.  You have an offset from UTC.  See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, `DateFormatter` is no help since you don't want a `Date` nor does it provide any information about any timezone info about a parsed date string. And `TimeZone` doesn't have any initializer that can parse a timezone offset string.

So you will have to do the work yourself. Since you have a fixed format date string, you know the timezone offset is always going to be the last 6 characters of the string. The last 2 of those are the number of minutes and the first 3 of those are the number of hours (including the sign).

Extract these two substrings (hours and minutes) from the date string. Convert them both to `Int`. Then do some simple math to calculate an offset in seconds (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60).

Once you have that offset in seconds, you can create a `TimeZone` instance using the `init(secondsFromGMT:)` initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Using [rmaddys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124150) proposed solution, I wrote an extension for `TimeZone` which should do the job.

```
extension TimeZone {
    init?(iso8601String: String) {
        let timeZoneString = String(iso8601String.suffix(6))
        let sign = String(timeZoneString.prefix(1))

        guard sign == "+" || sign == "-" else {
            return nil
        }

        let fullTimeString = timeZoneString.filter("0123456789".contains)

        guard fullTimeString.count == 4 else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let hours = Int(sign+fullTimeString.prefix(2)), let minutes = Int(sign+fullTimeString.suffix(2)) else {
            return nil
        }

        let secondsFromGMT = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60

        self.init(secondsFromGMT: secondsFromGMT)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a date formatter that only returns the time zone such as below. Change the abbreviation to whichever time zone you are looking for.

```
let timeZoneOnlyDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
  formatter.dateStyle = .none
  formatter.timeStyle = .none
  return formatter
}()
```

And use these functions to convert it to a string or convert your string to a date.

```
func formatDateIntoString(date: Date, dateFormatter: DateFormatter) -> String {
  return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}


func formatStringIntoDate(string: String, dateFormatter: DateFormatter) -> Date! {
  return dateFormatter.date(from: string)
}
```